# Changing route values breaks form submission...MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I changed my routes in global.asax so if a query string is manually typed in, the value is retained in the address bar:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Account", action = "LogOn", id = UrlParameter.Optional}   
        );
        routes.MapRoute(
            "OrderId", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{db}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Account", action = "LogOn", db = UrlParameter.Optional}                   );
```

I have 2 values here because the id parameter is used throughout the app like:

```
        public ActionResult AddNote(string id)
```

The db parameter is in case the user wants to connect to a different database and is entered via query string and retained in the url if something goes wrong, like bad username/password.

```
       thesite.com/?db=somedb
```

The app is working like before except for forms with no action specified like this one:

```
     @using (Html.BeginForm())
```

This form will render to the client as

```
 <form method="post" action="/UserTasks/NewOrder/Index">
```

The action "/UserTasks/NewOrder/Index" is never being called. No errors or anything. My original global.asax looked like this and the form would post back to the server as expected:

```
              routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id= UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

The Home/Index action was doing nothing but redirecting to Account/LogOn so thats why i eliminated the Home/Index call and go straight to Account/Logon an the home page.

What changes do i need to make in global.asax so all of my forms with no action explicitly entered will fire the default action that will be given to it by ASP.Net MVC like before? Thanks

Comment: Are you using *areas* in your app?

Comment: No im not...how do i use those?

Comment: just trying to make sense of your issue.. what route have you set up for /UserTasks/NewOrder/Index? Also, what particular route are you having trouble accessing?

Comment: What's `UserTasks`? The name of your application?